# Which HDL (hardware description language) Tesla is using to program the chips for their cars?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am learning VHDL at a university in Vivado and heard that in America there are using Verilog. So I wonder, which Hardware description language is using Tesla for programming it's chips?

Comment: If you can understand one language learning the other is easy.  Usually its the understanding of the technology that is more important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to find what kind of workers they are looking for in Tesla. Five minute search in google tells that they hire both VHDL and Verilog engineers.